# Convert Bson.M to a map[string]interface

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregation-framework, maps, bson

I'm trying to convert the structure I'm decoding with my query to `map[string]interface`.

Here is my code:

```
var m map[string]interface
var result []Result

type Result struct {
Id ResultId `bson:"_id"`
Filename string `bson:"filename"`
}

type ResultId struct {
Host string `bson:"host"`
}

group := bson.D{{"$group", bson.D{{"_id", bson.D{{"host","$host"}}}, {"filename", bson.D{{"$last","$filename"}}}}}}
collection := client.Database("mongodb").Collection("Meta")
cursor, err := collection.Aggregate(ctx, mongo.Pipeline{group})
if err != nil {
    return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
}
defer cursor.Close(ctx)
if err = cursor.All(ctx, &results); err != nil {
    fmt.Printf("cursor.All() error:", err)
    return c.JSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, err)
}
for _, value := range results {
    m = append(m,&bson.M{value.Id.Host:value.Filename})
}
```

But it does not return a map[string]interface and for information I use the go.mongodb.org package.

Comment: Can you please do as match as compile your code before posting it here? Formatting it properly can be also nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`append` only works on slices, (refer to [effective go's section](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go#append) for more on append)
The way to add elements to a map, is simply:

```golang
m["key"] = value
```

Also keep in mind maps need to be initialised which I don't see in your code. Either with `make` or by giving an initial value (can be an empty value)